# Wikipedia not loading images on modern browsers

Tags: image, google-chrome, firefox, browser, wikipedia

Wikipedia is a useful source of info but is less effective without images.

Due to security measures, modern browsers (latest updates of Firefox/Chrome/Safari) are not showing images which have origin different from that of host. eg: wikipedia.org page content is hosted on en.wikipedia.org but the media are hosted on upload.wikimedia.org, so the browsers are blocking all images.

I tried turning off browser security settings, adding wikipedia as exception, turning off https only requirement, altering site permissions, viewing on android wikipedia app (yes, even this fails as it can be a webview, thus using chrome browser internally to display content), etc. but to no avail.

What could be done to view the images on wikipedia?

Update: This issue has been resolved automatically (probably by wikimedia).

Comment: What browser would that be? Using a separate domain for images is a common technique, it would be poor behavior for a browser to break from that. It wouldn't provide meaningful security improvements either, as far as I can see.

Comment: Seems like some issue in India, all browsers working fine using VPN. Without VPN, this error is being displayed: "An error occurred during a connection to commons.wikimedia.org. PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR"

Comment: That sounds like something between your machine and Wikipedia (ISP? workplace router?) terminating connections. You might be able to do a traceroute to see where exactly the packet gets lost.